# Mercurial does not detect changes after MercurialEclipse plugin install

Tags: mercurial, mercurialeclipse

After installing the [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) Eclipse plugin, no more changes to any file are picked up by `hg`.

When I run

```
hg status
```

in the working directory, it returns nothing.

What could be at fault?

Comment: Are you running the command in the repository root from command line?

Comment: Yes. It worked, i.e. detected changes to files, before installing the plugin.

Comment: Strange... I have a similar setup for some of the engineers working with me and no problems. Is this Windows or Linux?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 12.10. Might I somehow be in the wrong branch? I'm sort of new to mercurial. :)

Comment: Try the following experiment:
1. Command prompt to root of repository. 2. Edit a file. 3. Run **hg status**.
Does it show now?

Comment: Do you have the .hg folder in there?